# How to make this polymer app responsive?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

https://gdg-test-ch.firebaseapp.com/

There are three cards in a row but there is some empty space in the right. in Mobile view the space become larger. Also the toolbar or nav bar is it fitting to the browser.

How can i make it responsive?

Card-view.html (card element)

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-card/paper-card.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html" />




  <dom-module id="card-view">


    <template>

      <style include="iron-flex iron-flex-layout">
        /* local styles go here */
        :host {
          display: block;
          max-width: 1450px;
        }
        .card {
          width: 300px;
          margin-left: 5px;
          margin-right: 5px;
          margin-bottom: 5px;
          margin-top: 5px;
        }
      </style>

      <!-- local DOM goes here -->
      <div class="container flex layout horizontal wrap">

<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{list}}">
        <div class="card">
          <paper-card heading="{{item.first}}" image="../image/{{item.last}}.jpg">

            <div class="card-actions">
                <paper-button>Explore!</paper-button>
              <paper-icon-button src="https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png"
               alt="octocat" title="octocat"></paper-icon-button>

            </div>
          </paper-card>
        </div>

</template>

      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'card-view',
        ready: function() {
            this.list = [
                {first: 'Bob', last: 'i'},
                {first: 'Sally', last: 'j'},
                {first: 'Sally', last: 'j'},
                {first: 'Sally', last: 'j'},
                {first: 'Sally', last: 'j'},
                {first: 'Sally', last: 'j'},
                {first: 'Sally', last: 'j'},
                {first: 'Sally', last: 'j'}


            ];
          }
      });
    </script>

  </dom-module>
```

Index.html (main page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="elements/card-view.html" />
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html" />

</head>




 <body>
<style>
a,.anchor-like,
.markdown-html a{
  color: var(--default-primary-color);
  text-decoration:none;
}
body {
  background-color: #FF5722;
}
</style>
<paper-toolbar>
  <span class="title">Title</span>
</paper-toolbar>
<card-view></card-view>






</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you want to make the cards sit in the middle and for the row length to get smaller before cards go off the the screen.

You want media queries and some maths :-)

Each card has a width of 300px + a 5px margin (on each side), meaning each one takes up 310px of space on the screen.

Lets say we never want to display more than 4 cards in a row that means we never want 'card-view' the have a greater with of 4x310px (1240px)

when we have less than 1240px of space we want to change to 3x310px so on and so forth.

```
card-view {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1240px) {
  card-view {
    width: 1240px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 930px) and (max-width: 1239px) {
  card-view {
    width: 930px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 620px) and (max-width: 929px) {
  card-view {
    width: 620px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 310px)  and (max-width: 619px) {
  card-view {
    width: 310px;
  }
}
```

Here is a link to the concept https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/bzr9wt00/